# How do I add extra rows to an Excel sheet via ODBC?

Tags: excel, dbvisualizer, odb

I used ODBC to create a sheet in Excel and add a row to it.

Literally the commands were just:

```
create table 'update5' ('age' NUMBER);
insert into 'update5'.'age' values (1);
```

This works and I can see the rows in the sheet and via DBVisualiser and my ODBC query results.

Later, I wrote more SQL to add another row like so:

```
insert into 'update5' ('age') values (2);
```

but I get the error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Cannot expand named range.

I do not know why named ranges are being used, is there a way I can set ODBC to not use them?

Comment: I'm confused - where were you entering these commands?   `INSERT INTO` is not for returning data, it's for adding records to an existing table.  `SELECT` would be what you use to view data.  There's something being miscommunicated, could you clarify a bit more, and maybe add a screenshot or something more descriptive?

Comment: Argh - stupid multiple windows open!!!  The title is incorrect for this question, I will edit it in a second.  I am entering the commands in a script which is being run via the ODBC engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

When you create an table in Excel via ODBC you create a named range of the same name within that table.

When you try to insert like this:

```
insert into 'update5'.'age' values (2);
```

It is interpreted as you trying to add to the the named range called update5 which is inside the table update5.

You need to use the syntax:

```
insert into [update5$].'age' values (2);
```

to add values to the table called update5.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about what your doing, what you're working with, and your end-goal I can't give a definite answer - however, if you're saying this works fine as-is:

```
create table 'update5' ('age' NUMBER);
insert into 'update5'.'age' values (1);
```

...then it stands to reason that this:

```
insert into update5 values (2);
```

...will not work because your missing:

- quotation marks (which may or may not be optional in your environment), and,
- the field name to which you want to export.

In the first `insert into` statement you have:

```
'update5'     <-- the destination table
.'age'        <-- the destination field
 values (1);  <-- the value to insert
```

...so if you're just trying to add a record with the number `2` to the same field, **use the same code**:

```
insert into 'update5'.'age' values (2);
```

---

### More Information:

- w3schools : [**SQL INSERT INTO Statement**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)
- TutorialsPoint : [**SQL INSERT Query** (Tutorial)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-insert-query.htm)

Comment: Sorry, the question contains an error.  The actual SQL being generated has the relevant formatting.  I have edited the question accordingly